# Want to select top 1 row of a table

Tags: database

```
select TOP 1 CITY from (select * from STATION order by CITY DESC);
```

I want to selct top city when i order it by descending order.

Getting below error

RROR 1064 (42000) at line 4: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 CITY from (select * from STATION order by CITY DESC)' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql does not use TOP, it uses LIMIT

```
select CITY from STATION order by CITY DESC limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you query should be like this

```
SELECT TOP 1 CITY FROM STATION ORDER BY CITY DESC
```